# IIS7 on Windows 7 and DefaultAppPool - file security

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, iis

What is DefaultAppPool?

In task manager, I can see that w3wp.exe is running as DefaultAppPool. My web site reports that it is executing as DefaultAppPool, but I cannot specify it in file security as a user to give read/write access to a config file I have.

Why? Is it another name for some other account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultAppPool is an application pool. Application pools are used to provide different levels of isolation for your web applications.

The default process identity for 'DefaultAppPool' is NetworkService.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this name in that dialog to find it

IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

I believe that with IIS 7.5 network service no longer applies